# cant seem to get reactnative app created on ubuntu keep getting error: Cannot find module 'fs-minipass'

Tags: react-native, expo

Can't create react native application on terminal

```
expo init first_project
```

Cannot find module f_s mini_pass

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you installed `create-react-native-app` and `expo-cli`. And assuming you are using linux.

First uninstall both:

```
sudo npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save

sudo npm -g uninstall create-react-native-app --save
```

and then you just install expo-cli:

```
sudo install -g expo-cli
```

You can now create a new app:

```
expo init Awesome-app
```

It should work now.